# Display date in dd/mm/yy format, not whole number, in a vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, date

I need to see a "dd/mm/yy" format in my TextBox, but a whole number is appearing.

I tried some dd/mm/yy in the code, but it doesn't solve the problem.

```
Me.txtDate.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(AssetTag, Sheets("Assets").Range("A2:N1087"), 9, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a whole number, then at least the `Vlookup()` is working.  Try:

```
    Dim N As Long, s As String
    N = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(AssetTag, Sheets("Assets").Range("A2:N1087"), 9, 0)
    s = Format(N, "dd/mm/yy")
    Me.txtDate.Value = s
```

Comment: Do I need to paste it on the combo box or on the txt box that the date was assign?